# Google Workflows only returning the first 20 documents in a collection

Tags: google-workflows

I have a simple Workflows that starts with retrieving the documents from a Firebase collection, but for some reason, the call only returns the ***first 20 documents*** from the collection.

Workflows is written in YAML -- Is there a limitation I am unaware of?

```
main:
  params: [input]
  steps:
  - initialize:
      assign:
        - project: "dev"
        - collection: "shops"

  - shops:
      steps:
      - get_documents:
          call: googleapis.firestore.v1.projects.databases.documents.get
          args:
            name: ${"projects/" + project + "/databases/(default)/documents/" + collection}
          result: documents

  - endit:
      return: ${documents.documents}
```

Answer (score 4):

Resolved, I added a pageSize to the query param

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/list

```
  - shops:
      steps:
      - get_documents:
          call: googleapis.firestore.v1.projects.databases.documents.get
          args:
            name: ${"projects/" + project + "/databases/(default)/documents/" + collection}
            query:
              pageSize: 10000
          result: documents
```